# Cannot inspect component properties while debugging Blazor WebAssembly code-behind files in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, debugging, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I recently converted my Blazor Server app over to Blazor WebAssembly and noticed debugging in Visual Studio 2019 no longer works properly.

I can still step through my components and inspect local variables, but I can no longer inspect my component's properties in any way. Visual Studio tells me 'Unable to Evaluate'.

My code is structured using a code-behind approach. I have discovered that if I merge the code files directly into a @code block in the component then the problem goes away. But I'd prefer not to do this as it seems like a step backwards.

Example 1. Code directly embedded in the component... Inspecting properties works OK

**Counter.razor**

```
@page "/Counter"
<DebugChild Max="20"></DebugChild>
```

**DebugChild.razor**

```
<h2>DebugChild</h2>
@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public int Max { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var x = Max; //I can inspect Max here
    }
}
```

Example 2. Code split out into a code-behind file... Inspecting properties DOES NOT work

**Counter.razor**

```
@page "/Counter"
<DebugChild Max="20"></DebugChild>
```

**DebugChild.razor**

```
@inherits BlazorWASMHosted.Client.Components.DebugChild
<h2>DebugChild</h2>
```

**DebugChild.razor.cs**

```
Using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
namespace BlazorWASMHosted.Client.Components
{
   public class DebugChild : ComponentBase
    {
        [Parameter]
        public int Max { get; set; }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            var x = Max;  //I CANNOT inspect Max here
        }
    }
}
```

I tried doing the code-behind using partial classes instead of interitance and had no luck there either. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You're no longer debugging server-side code, you're debugging *in the browser*. The VS debugger only knows what the browser tells it. `Locals` works for example, but on the fly inspection doesn't. Check [Debug ASP.NET Core WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs). And any breakpoints you put in `OnInitialized` won't be hit the first time

Comment: BTW this means we get even less information than we would with Javascript and may have to resort to `Console.WriteLine` to inspect values

Comment: UPDATE... 
I finally got it working. I can now inspect everything (properties, complex types returned service calls etc) in my code behind files. 
It appears you must use the newer partial class code-behind approach rather than the older Inheriting from a base class technique.

Comment: I had tried the partial class approach before, but I didn't have my code-behind's namespace set correctly. The razor.cs file needs to have a namespace which matches the implied namespace of the razor file. (which is its project folder structure)

Another thing I found is that if you find your breakpoints aren't being hit, then clean or rebuild your solution then try again.